# Ignore empty matches while glob expanding on bash for loop

Tags: bash, glob

I'm writing a script to move files (*Dropbox Camera Uploads*, for instance) to ***year named folders***, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Separate (camera) images on directory
# to year named folders.
#
# All files must be named as "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ext"
#
for img in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
  year=${img:0:4}
  [ -d "$year" ] || mkdir "$year"
  mv -iv "$img" "$year/"
done
```

The script works as expected for matchin files, but when there isn't any file with some extension, expands to `*.ex` (first two extension chars). Then it creates empty directories as follows:

```
'*.jp'
'*.jp'
'*.pn'
```

How can I just ignore no matching files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `nullglob` option; patterns that don't match anything are ignored, rather than treated literally.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.does_not_exist; do
    echo "This won't be reached"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two primary options.  One, as @chepner suggests, is to turn on `nullglob`, which makes unmatched globs expand to null:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

The other is to test to see if the file is there before doing anything with it:

```
for img in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
  if [ -f "$img" ]; then   # not true for '*.jpg' etc
    year=${img:0:4}
    [ -d "$year" ] || mkdir "$year"
    mv -iv "$img" "$year/"
  fi
done
```

You could also use `mkdir -p` and skip the `-d` test.

Comment: Yes, I would use the test. But the nullglob options seens cleaner. Not sure if i'ts safer.

Comment: Thanks for the `-p` tip.

Comment: @paulodiovani The main difference is that `nullglob` is bash-specific, the test is portable to most shells.

Answer (score 1):

you can check to see if the file exists first, then `continue` the loop if not

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Separate (camera) images on directory
# to year named folders.
#
# All files must be named as "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ext"
#
for img in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
  [ ! -f "$img" ] && continue
  year=${img:0:4}
  [ -d "$year" ] || mkdir "$year"
  mv -iv "$img" "$year/"
done
```